OutOfMemory Error When Converting Spring Boot Health Indicators to Micrometer Metrics
When trying to export the Spring Boot health indicators as metrics with Micrometer. I followed the Mapping Health Indicators to Micrometer Metrics  to implement the same. The implementation is as follows

@Configuration
public class HealthApiToMetricsConvertor {


    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> healthRegistryCustomizer(HealthContributorRegistry healthRegistry,
                                                                           HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
        return new MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry>() {
            @Override
            public void customize(MeterRegistry registry) {

                registry.gauge("health",Tags.of("name","root"), healthEndpoint, it -> healthToCode(it.health().getStatus()));
                healthRegistry
                        .stream()
                        .forEach(
                                namedContributor -> registry.gauge(
                                        "health",
                                        Tags.of("name", namedContributor.getName()),
                                        healthRegistry,
                                        health -> {
                                            var status = ((HealthIndicator) health.getContributor(namedContributor.getName()))
                                                    .getHealth(false).getStatus();
                                            return healthToCode(status);
                                        }
                                )
                        );
            }
        };
    }

    private int healthToCode(Status status) {
        return status.equals(Status.UP) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}



While building and running the test  (using the test-container)I am facing an OutOfMemory error.
Following are the memory metrics.

When the HealthApiToMetricsConvertor class is commented out there is no memory leak.

Could someone please tell me the possible cause and solution? If I've missed anything, or over- or under-emphasized a specific point, please let me know in the comments. Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Is it possible that this causes an infinite loop somehow?
You can check the gauges this creates in multiple ways: 1. using the actuator endpoint: /actuator/metrics/health, check how many tags you have 2. SimpleMeterRegistry has a getMetersAsString method, you can print them out 3. if you add the Prometheus registry, you can see them on /actuator/prometheus 4. There is a HighCardinalityTagsDetector, if you configure it, it should tell you if you have a metrics with unbounded tags (causes OOM) and which one is it.

@Nithin Varghese, have you tried to rewrite that w/o using lambdas at all? Based on my experience lambdas tends to take on the role of GC roots due to their design, and IMO using lambdas in spring configurations actually is a bad practice.

@AndreyB.Panfilov there way to  rewrite that w/o using lambdas or inner class

Disclaimer: I didn't try this out, so it might not be exactly what you need, but it should give you an idea of where it might be going wrong.
Looking at your code, I think this is where it goes wrong: in your second call of the registry.gauge(...) method, you are passing healthRegistry instead of healthPoint, and you are doing this for each contributor of the healthRegistry object. If the gauge(...) method iterates over each contributor you can imagine how quickly the memory will fill up and throw an OutOfMemoryException.
Try something like this:
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry>
healthRegistryCustomizer(HealthContributorRegistry healthRegistry, HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
    return registry -> {
        registry.gauge("health", Tags.of("name", "root"), healthEndpoint, it -> healthToCode(it.health().getStatus()));
        healthRegistry.stream().forEach(namedContributor ->
                registry.gauge("health", Tags.of("name", namedContributor.getName()),
                        healthEndpoint,
                        doubleValues -> {
                            var status = doubleValues.health().getStatus();
                            return healthToCode(status);
                        }
                )
        );
    };
}

private int healthToCode(Status status) {
    return status.equals(Status.UP) ? 1 : 0;
}


even the       registry.gauge("health", Tags.of("name", "root"), healthEndpoint, it -> healthToCode(it.health().getStatus())); is causing the  OutOfMemoryException

Can you put some logs/counters and try to pinpoint the cause?

Disclaimer: I didn't try this out, so it might not be exactly what you need.
Iterate healthRegistry directly and avoid creating streams that might retain excessive memory and pass in health indicator directly instead of passing in health registry like this:
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> healthRegistryCustomizer(HealthContributorRegistry healthRegistry, HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
    return registry -> {
        registry.gauge("health", Tags.of("name", "root"), healthEndpoint, 
            it -> healthToCode(it.health().getStatus()));
        
        healthRegistry.forEach(namedContributor -> {
            if (namedContributor.getContributor() instanceof HealthIndicator) {
                HealthIndicator healthIndicator = (HealthIndicator) namedContributor.getContributor();
                registry.gauge("health", Tags.of("name", namedContributor.getName()), 
                    healthIndicator, 
                    it -> healthToCode(it.getHealth(false).getStatus()));
            }
        });
    };
}


Adding management.metrics.use-global-registry=false to application.yml seems to reduce the heap while doing the testing. the global registry is actually a static attribute of the Metrics utility class, which could be the reason.
need to check its behaviour in the test containers / test context
